# How do I display detailed JSON-API JS debugging information in the console?

Tags: node.js

I want to view the detailed output of JSON-API JS in the console so that I can diagnose the errors that I am getting.

At the moment errors display as: `POST /api/v1/resources/resource 500 39.998 ms - 103`

I want to get more information about why JSON-API is throwing an error.

Comment: Could you please add correct tag? [json-api] refers to JSON API specification. Seems like you are dealing with a node.js application / framework that is named similar.

Comment: Done, thanks @jelhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply prefix the command to start your entire server process with `DEBUG=json-api:*`

In my case my command to start the development server is now: `DEBUG=json-api:* yarn start`